# How to use a "LocalBroadcastManager" throughout the app?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a fragment showing a list of products. Each list item has a watchlist button showing a transparent heart icon if it is not watchlisted and a red heart icon if it is watchlisted.The user can click this heart icon in the listing page to watchlist or unwatchlist the product.

When clicking upon the body of an item, the user can go to the product details page.
Here also there is a watchlist button.

The functionality I wanted is that when the user clicks the watchlist icon in the details page, it should also change the watchlist icon in the listing page when the user goes back from the details page to the listing page.

For this I used the local broadcast manager so that when the user clicks the watchlist icon in the details page, it sends a broadcast with the product id and the watchlist status. I just change the adapter json array data with the details send by the broadcast on to the receiver I wrote on the listing page and notify dataset changed.

My question is that when should I unregister this receiver which I wrote on the listing page?

I just cannot unregister the listing page broadcast receiver as I want to receive an event sent from the details page which is another page.

This is the receiver I wrote on the listing page.

```
final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiverWatchlist = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                try{
                    LogHelper.logReadyMadeString("aaaaaaaaa13");
                    String product_id = intent.getStringExtra("productId");
                    String watchlistStatus = intent.getStringExtra("wishlistStatus");
                    for(int i=0;i<totalProductJsonArray.length();i++){
                    if(totalProductJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("product_id").equalsIgnoreCase(productId)){
                        totalProductJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).put("watchlist",watchlistStatus);
                          productListingAdaterRv.notifyDataSetChanged();
                          break;
                        }
                        }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverWatchlist, filter);
```

Here is the code I wrote on the details page to send a broadcast to the listing page

```
Intent intentToBroadCast = new Intent();

intentToBroadCast.setAction("com.applicationid.broadcast.WATCHLIST_NOTIFICATION");
intentToBroadCast.putExtra("wishlistStatus",watchlistStatus);
intentToBroadCast.putExtra("productId",productId);

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intentToBroadCast);
```

The code is working fine. I watchlist a product in its details page. It sends a broadcast in the listing page and changes the watchlist status of the corresponding product id.

I want to know when if not should I unregister the receiver in the listing page?

Thanks for your time. If any doubt please inform me.

Note: The product listing page is a fragment in the home activity. The product details page is altogether a different activity.

Comment: you can unregister this broadcaster inside `onStop` of that Activity

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit But if I unregister the receiver on the home activity where the product listing fragment is present, then how will it receive the broadcast from the details activity page?

Comment: If you are using v4 fragment, it has method onStop. what you can do is write your Broadcast Receiver in side that fragment and unregister inside that fragment itself.

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit If i unregister it on fragment onStop method, can it get the broadcast sent from the details activity page? Anyways thanks for your patience.

Comment: yeap it will. as long as your fragment is there. and not stopped.

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit But the fragment will get stopped right? The fragment onStop method will be called if I move from listing fragment, which is in the home activity, to product details activity?

Answer (score 1):

Just do unregister work in the `onDestroy` of the ProductListFragment

Comment: But if I unregister on the ondestroy method of the product list fragment, can it receive the watchlist event I broadcasted on the product details page?

Comment: Yes,the product list fragment is stopped but not destroyed when startActivity from the home activity to the product details page activity.But here use startActivityForResult&setResult to send back if  the product's watchlisted status is changed is better.

Comment: I am sorry but startActivityForResult cannot be coded here due to some structural reasons. I really need the answer regarding broadcast.

Comment: @debo.stackoverflow Do u try unregister in the onDestroy? Does it works?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am gonna do it today and notify in this page.